# While setting apptheme for ActionBar, I got this weird error red color is private. What is that mean?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set background color of ActionBar ,I found that I can't use red color as it is private instead I have to use holo_red_dark but why, does anybody has explanation.

[image: error: resource android:color/red is private.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like your application has it's colors in a `colors.xml` file so do the components of the Android system and this is one of them. In the same manner, you can't (actually you can but you really shouldn't) use them in your application because they are the design of the system and may change.
You can see the value of the color in the [source code of Android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml).

Answer (score 0):

red color in android is private You can reference them like this

```
android:drawable="@*android:color/red"
```

but it is not recommended, because private resources are likely to be renamed or removed in the future.
i suggest add custom color in your colors.xml file resource.

Comment: got your point could you please suggest me some reference for that.